# Aplication with route http://localhost:9000/#!/

Tags: angular, routes

I have an application in angular 1.6 which loads a simple html with a service and a controller... my question is in the url is this part:

http://localhost:9000**/#!/**

**#! what does that mean and how can I remove it? is it really needed? And when I call a service I see it is sended like:**

http://url.dev.unix.ban.com:8081/DEVMFPBem01/api/adapters/paykeyAdapter/registrar/transferenciaSpei**/#!/**

app.js :

```
    (function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
  .module('myApp', [
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');



    $stateProvider
      .state('main', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/quote-comps.html',
        controller: 'MainT',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      });
  });  

  /*
  .constant('myConfig', {
    api: 'entuzona-1/'
  });*/
})();
```

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Comment: I added    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); but it stills load with the #!

Comment: it works now thanks I missed the base part